# What's the difference between using duckduckgo with !google bangs and using google directly?

Tags: google, tracking, search-engines, duckduckgo

Is there any security advantage in searching on duckduckgo using !google? Or is it effectively the same as searching directly on google?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no difference: **DuckDuckGo doesn't offer any privacy protection when redirecting** the search to another result page with a `!bang`. E.g. `!google foo` (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!google+foo) just redirects to https://google.com/search?hl=en&q=foo using both

- meta refresh

  ```
  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=https://google.com/search?hl=en&q=foo'>
  ```
- and JavaScript

  ```
  <script language='JavaScript'>
      function ffredirect(){
          window.location.replace('https://google.com/search?hl=en&q=foo');
      }
      setTimeout('ffredirect()',100);
  </script>
  ```
- ...but not with an actual HTTP redirect, probably in order to hide itself as the referrer:

  ```
  <meta name='referrer' content='never'>
  ```

On the other hand, it prevents Google from getting direct information on the keystrokes and typos through Ajax queries:

[image: Google search JSON example]